# closest() traversing not working in my case

Tags: jquery

I want to use closest to traverse select an item, my html as below :

```
<span id='target'></span>
<a></a>
```

jquery

```
assume 'a' = $(this),
then I do $(this).closest('#target');
```

but it seem it doesn't select the #target.. what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Closest('#target')` isn't going to work here since the `a` tag is a sibling to `span#target` not a parent. Use `Closest` to find the parent element for both of these and then do a find to get your `target` span, or just use `.prev` to get sibling `target` span.

```
$(this).closest("div").find("#target");
```

or

```
$(this).prev("#target");
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this since you have an `id`, why can't the `id` selector be used

Answer (score 1):

Since you have and id, you can use it as an id-selector because id will be unique in a document - there is no need to use any relational lookup in this case.

```
var target = $('#target')
```

If you have a pattern like above where a `anchor` element is followed by a `span` element then use a class attribute instead of `id`. In such a case the `span` is the previous sibling of the `anchor` element so you need to use [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

```
<span class='target'></span>
<a></a>

var target = $(this).prev('.target');// $(this).prev() is sufficient
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will look for an ancestor element, not for a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Closes does not check siblings, it check element and its parents [jQuery.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

In your case `<a>` and `<span>` are siblings, not parent/child - so using `closest` will not find `span` starting from `a`.